# How can I split a partition in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

I have a yearly partition on a table.
I need to split the same into two half yearly partitions.
How can this be achieved in SAP HANA ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the SAP document SAP HANA Database - Partitioning and Distributing Data for more info, but you could create a range partition containing months.

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE mytab (a INT, b INT, c INT, PRIMARY KEY (a,b))
    PARTITION BY RANGE (a)
        (PARTITION 1 <= VALUES < 5,
          PARTITION 5 <= VALUES < 20,
          PARTITION VALUE = 44,
          PARTITION OTHERS)
```

- Create partitions for ranges using <= VALUES < semantics
- Create partitions for single values using VALUE = semantics
- Create a rest partition for all values that do not match the other ranges using PARTITION OTHERS

So for your case specifically (assuming month values of 1 to 12) you could do something like this:

```
(PARTITION 1 <= VALUES < 7,
  PARTITION 7 <= VALUES < 12,
  PARTITION OTHERS)
```